# How to erase or disappear black borders in cv::Mat matrix or image

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, matrix

These are 2 similar images.

I have their cv::mat matrix too.

[image: http://img.over-blog-kiwi.com/0/46/98/26/201310/ob_299e3e65acd32f2b11866b54039fc1ad_ag-drone-5.jpg]

[image: http://img.over-blog-kiwi.com/0/46/98/26/20140319/ob_b3841d_mosaicing-0-1.png]

How can I disappear/erase/delete the black borders in cv::Mat matrix or the image(png)?

Like this:

[image: http://img.over-blog-kiwi.com/0/46/98/26/20140319/ob_d37014_effi-mosaicing.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution, assuming that the image's background color is uniform, could be to loop through each pixel in the cv::Mat and, if a pixel matches the background colour (let's say RGB(0,0,0), or pure black), it replaces this pixel with another colour (let's say (RGB(255,255,255), or pure white).

Of course, this would remove any pure black pixels in our image that we want to preserve. Thus, you could experiment with different thresholds of pixel values to remove, instead of just pure black. You can either threshold the RGB channel, or convert to another colour space (i.e. HSV) and apply a threshold to just one channel (i.e. the Value channel).